# Show list name in workflow email

Tags: workflow, email

I created a reusable workflow in SPD 2010 to be used with Calendars (Event content type).  Is there any way I can add a lookup to display the LIST(Calendar) name?

An example:  User has access to Calendar's 1,3 and 5.  When the workflow fires, I want to add the name of the calendar in the subject or email body.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable to the Workflow Context:Current Item URL. This saves the URL Path of the List within the newly created variable. After that just extract a substring at the position of the Listname.

site/Lists/NameOfList/AllItems.aspx

Then just get the substring after Lists/ up to until /AllItems

Hope this works.