# List name as string in email

Tags: list, workflow, email

Is there a way to get the current list name as a string in an email?
Say that I got a workflow that emails me when the list is edited, and in this email I want the name of the list that's edited as a string.

Comment: Are you working with 2010 workflows, or 2013 workflows?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/74546/8992)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify what version of Sharepoint you are using.
I know it can be done on 2013 with SharePoint Designer 2013.
Bellow on image is how to do that.
[image]

Practically you click on Fx at **Subject**, on pop-up window for Data source choose Workflow Context and at Field from source choose List Name. Return field automatically is String.

Answer (score 0):

In your Email body at your workflow

Insert lookup for string >

- at Datasource select `Workflow Context` > .
- select `List Name` from Field from source .

[image]

Note : this image only example where you need to select `List Name`

Comment: I'm using designer 2010 for this workflow and for me it's Workflow context -> Association name. But this is really weird, it worked a couple of days ago but now instead of the list's name it gives med the name of the workflow?

Comment: you still have issue ?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried all the options under Workflow context. None of them give me the list name. But it should be "association name", it worked before. Very weird.

Comment: I solved it in another way instead for the use.

Comment: I am sorry for late response great, post your solution  as answer to be useful for all